# Nested linked list in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a nested linked list in C++ (pretty new to C++).
The node in the list could be an integer value or another linked list that has all integer values.

I have gone through other posts on SO, and I understand I should use a union for multiple data types for the node data type.
This is what I have until now.

```
class linkedList {
private:
    struct node {
        union data {
            int val;
            linkedList* list;
        };
        data currData;           
        node* next;             // a pointer which will point to the next node
    }*p;
```

My question is how do I start allocating the list pointer within the node struct.
For val, I know I can do `p->currData->val =5`, for example.

Comment: Rather than using a union, look into `std::variant`.  It has the benefit of 'knowing' what type of data it contains.

Comment: eg: `struct node { std::variant<int, linkedList> currData; node* next; } *p;` And while you are at it, consider replacing your manual linked-list with the standard [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) class, eg: `class linkedList { private: std::list<std::variant<int, linkedList>> p; ... };`

Comment: Remember that somebody needs to put away all of the nodes when you're done playing with them or you'll have a memory leak. That by itself is a really good reason to use `std::list`. Irf you don't, you need to figure out whether you're using the `int` or the pointer so you can put away all of the linked nodes, and that's where `std::variant` really becomes helpful. And if you still choose to go it alone, make sure `linkedList` observes at least [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Side note: Consider storing the `linkedList` directly rather than by a pointer. A properly written singly linked list shouldn't be that much bigger than a pointer, probably two pointers (head and tail) and a count of links in the list as the worst case, and will be an easier clean-up than the pointer..

Comment: The reason I'm not using std::list or std::variant is purely due to learning purposes about pointers and memory allocation/deallocation. 

@user4581301 Could you please clarify what do you mean by storing linkedlist directly rather than a pointer?

Comment: `union data { int val; linkedList list; };` <- Look ma! No pointers! The downside here is you will have to learn [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), and following that through to the logical conclusion, you're no better off, complexity-wise, than using a pointer. But you learn a cool new trick.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a union. I would just keep a value for each and a `type`field of some sort so you know what it is.

```
 class LinkedList {
 public:
     class Node {
          LinkedList * list = nulptr;
          int value = 0;
          Node * next = nullptr;
     };
 };
```

In this case, if list is nullptr, then it's not a node pointing to a new list. Or you could explicitly add a `type`, but for something this simple, I probably wouldn't.

```
 p->value = 5;
```

Comment: How would I initialize the list pointer? I mean, how would this compile? Because when the Node class is compiling, it doesn't know the LinkedList class yet. Am I right?

Comment: It's an inner class. It absolutely knows what a LinkedList * is. Did you try the code?